# Java 8, stream with another List Index based on

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I have this code

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(30, 25, 17, 12 ,8, 5, 3, 2));
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>(5, 3, 2));
Integer newNumber = 1;
for (int i = indices.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  newNumber *= (numbers.get(indices.get(i)));
}
```

`newNumber` will be: `5*12*17 = 1020`

It is possible to do using stream reduce?

Later I need to remove the indices from the original numbers (I was thinking in filter, but the target is the  index not Integer object).

```
List<Integer> newNumbers = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
for (int i = indices.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  newNumbers.remove(indices.get(i).intValue()); // Remove position
}
```

Alternatively, I was thinking in this code.

```
List<Integer> newNumbers2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
  if (!indices.contains(i)) {
    newNumbers2.add(numbers.get(i));
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do it using stream?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need/want streams here?

Comment: I performs complex operation, stream allow me parallels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using simple reduction. The identity element of the the reduction is 1 in this case.

```
int product = indices.stream().mapToInt(numbers::get).reduce(1, (n1, n2) -> n1 * n2);
```

The answer for the latter question would be,

```
Set<Integer> indicesSet = new HashSet<>(indices);
List<Integer> newNumbers = IntStream.range(0, numbers.size())
    .filter(n -> !indicesSet.contains(n))
    .mapToObj(n -> numbers.get(n))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> In mathematics, an identity element is a special type of element of a
>   set with respect to a binary operation on that set, which leaves any
>   element of the set unchanged when combined with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *indices are sorted in reverse order*, a single pipeline for both your operations using a sequential stream could be:

```
int product = indices.stream().sequential()
        .mapToInt(index -> numbers.remove((int) index))
        .reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
```

*Note*: The use of [`List.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) here is with respect to removing an element from the index and not the object and hence casting to `(int)`.

Comment: But even if the indices are sorted as you want, the Stream API does not guaranty that the *processing order* will match that. It happens to work for a sequential stream, but you should not rely on it.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for chipping in. I do understand the processing order guarantees are a risk with the solution and I did quote it keeping sequential streams in mind. Curious: Why should one not rely on the sequential streams for this solution to work? Do let me know, I would be happier to ask it as a separate question if the details are worth being shared across.

Comment: It’s an implementation detail that the processing order coincides with the encounter order in sequential execution, but it’s not a guaranteed behavior. Just because we can’t imagine today, how an implementation could exploit the permission to process elements in a different order, we can’t assume that this will always be the case. Another point is that it is dangerous to use an API in an unintended way, as the next reader might not be aware of the fragility and either, change the code in a way the looks valid but breaks it or copy parts of it to another context, where it does not always work.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove the index from the list numbers with the list indices.

```
List<Integer> newNumbers = numbers.stream().filter(num ->           
            !indices.contains(numbers.indexOf(num)) 
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an int overflow I would recommend using [`Math.multiplyExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact(int,int)) for the multiplication. To prevent `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s you should filter the indices first:

```
int newNumber = indices.stream()
        .filter(i -> i < numbers.size())
        .mapToInt(numbers::get)
        .reduce(Math::multiplyExact)
        .orElseThrow();
```

If you want to multiply the numbers anyway you should map them to long values:

```
long nNumber = indices.stream()
        .filter(i -> i < numbers.size())
        .mapToLong(numbers::get)
        .reduce(Math::multiplyExact)
        .orElseThrow();
```

Alternatively to `orElseThrow()` you can use `orElse()` if you want to return a default value for an empty stream.

To remove the indices from the `numbers` array you can use this:

```
indices.stream()
        .filter(i -> i < numbers.size())
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .mapToInt(i -> i)
        .forEach(numbers::remove);
```